# Azure blob storage and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure

So i have been using Azure DB for a while, but i ran in problem that I can't store in Azure large files and as a solution I found Storage Account.

To make queries I used tedious (JS). Can I save and recieve data via JS?

Comment: The short answer is yes, but can you share what code you have tried so far? Will help identify any bugs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know tedious is for interacting with SQL server.  You may want to check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/storage-blob for interacting with Azrue Blob storage service.